# Pi 2/3 (Buster installed) to Pi 4 migration, what is to consider?

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, pi-2, raspbian-buster

I found many comments, that the migration from pi2/3 to pi4 requires some changes, mainly because the boot partition has to be larger there.

But in my understanding, the boot partition size isn't related to the hardware. 
Means, if I've installed a Buster-Debian system on my rpi2/3, it will work with rpi4 as well, without any change, right? 
Could I switch this card between all rpi versions then?

Comment: Buster fully updated should work on all Pi's.

Comment: Don't believe all the rubbish you find posted on the internet. Most by people who ignore the official recommendation to do fresh install. If it was a fresh Buster Install it will work if you update.

Comment: *"the boot partition size"* -> I doubt very much the Pi 4 SoC checks this for some specific value (I create my own partitions, so this would have to be quite the coincidence).  The size used in the images has grown over the years as the boot partition has come to contain more and more things, that's all.